# ET_ClickEvent Get() does not return results consistently

Tags: fuel

I'm using the ET_ClickEvent class in FUEL to retrieve these events for a specific user.  However I'm getting odd behaviour.  Sometimes it returns results, other times nothing.

I have a ComplexFilterPart which selects the subscriberKey (equal) and the CreatedDate (greaterThanOrEqual)

Running in .NET debug, sometimes I get the results back as expected (2 items) and sometimes it returns no results even though I have not changed anything.

Anyone have an idea?
cheers